# Getting SSL certificate issue in existing local site

Tags: certificate

Getting a SSL certificate issue in existing site in local system.

[image]

Could someone assist me how I can resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably your website uses wrong certificate or certificate already expired.

**Create new certificate:**

Start powershell as administrator and run `New-SelfSignedCertificate` with proper parameters. Depending on your powershell version, you may need to include different set of parameters, so best check [New-SelfSignedCertificate documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps) if the one below doesn't work for you:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "your.local" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

That will create new certificate in your personal store.

**Add new certificate to trusted store**

Start Microsoft Management Console by running `mmc.exe`

[image]

Click `File` -> `Add/Remove Span-in`

[image]

Double click `Certificates` and select `Computer Account`, then select `Local computer` if asked.

Expand `Personal` and select `Certificates`. You should see your new certificate there. And potentially the old one as well. You can distinguish them by `Expiration Date`.

[image]

Remove the old one if it's there.

Copy new certificate to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates` (e.g. drag and drop with `ctrl` key pressed).

[image]

Check if new certificate is there in `Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates` and remove old one if it's there.

**Update binding on IIS**

Go to IIS manager, select your site and edit bindings. Select your new certificate:

[image]

**Retest in browser**

That should do the trick. Open your browser (best in private mode as certificates can be cached e.g. in chrome) and check if your new certificate is used and marked as secure:

[image]